# QgisMap renderer Design Methodology

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I wanted to know what drawing methodology is used by qgis renderer like gdi,gdi++ or opengl. I have searched its documentation http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapRendererJob.html 
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html
but didnt found any methodology used by its renderer for drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [Qt](http://www.qt.io/), which abstracts away specific platform-specific technologies.

Note that you can [download and build the source yourself](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.html), so you have full visibility into the detailed implementation of QGIS. Similarly, you can build Qt from source, and examine that.

Comment: i am asking about rendering maps. Like when you load shape file then how that data is rendered on qgis?

Comment: The source code is authoritative.